# Calendar - Non repeating events displaying in multiple months, how to fix it?

Tags: views, datetime

I have normal events which are displaying correctly in the month they should but they also appear in the first line (week) of each month after.

I have tried removing the events and creating them again, creating the calendar from scratch but still they appear.

I'm not sure what extra details would help in answering this so if there is anything you need just let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a guess as its hard to say without more details but its most likely to do with contextual filters not set up correctly. For month I have them set up as follows:

Provide default value: current date
Granularity: month
Dates to compare: Start/End date range
Add multiple value identifier: Yes
Content: Dates - start date (field_event_date)
Method: OR

For week its exactly the same except using week granularity and so on for days and years. Make sure you dont have any other calendar views (even disabled ones were playing tricks on me before). Also make sure your sort is based on the same date field as the contextual filter.

Comment: I managed to get it working, the problem seems to have come from the contextual filter having two date fields while the sort only had one of them.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.